# CSS issue using Knockout.js

Tags: css

I'm using Chrome.

There should be a silver underline under the "First name    Last name    Phone numbers" header and it should be for each contact. The intent is to show each contact as a set so it puts a silver line after each 1.

Here's a snapshot of the example from Knockout.js as to what it should look like - http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html:

[image]

For my version (which I created from their sample code), the border-bottom won't show and I don't know why...any ideas?

It sees my style.css file and the CSS rule:

```
.liveExample table.contactsEditor > tbody > TR { border-bottom: 1px solid silver; }
```

The odd thing is I do NOT have a tbody element surrounding the tr for the 3 th elements in my index.html file. But when I inspect mine, it is there. The Knockout.js example's HTML that I copied it from does NOT have it either. However, when I inspect knockout's, it is in theirs too. The CSS knockout put forth has that tbody included in it though.

Here's Knockout's example and some of their code is showing as well as the result of running it:

[image]

Here's a snapshot of my run:

[image]

Here's the style.css file:

```
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid 
#CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.liveExample input { font-family: Arial; }
.liveExample b { font-weight: bold; }
.liveExample p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.liveExample select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.liveExample h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; }
.liveExample TR { vertical-align: top; }
.liveExample TABLE, .liveExample TD, .liveExample TH { padding: 0.2em; 
border-width: 0; margin: 0; text-align: left; }
.liveExample TD A { font-size: 0.8em; text-decoration: none; }
.liveExample table.contactsEditor > tbody > TR { border-bottom: 1px solid 
silver; }
.liveExample td input { width: 8em; }
li { list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 20px; }
```

Here's the index.html (notice there is NOT a tbody element surrounding the tr for the 3 th elements):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <title>Contacts Editor</title>       

      <link href="C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Web Dev\Javascript and 
jQuery\Knockout.js\Examples\Contacts editor\style.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />   
    </head> 

    <body>
        <div class='liveExample'> 
            <h2>Contacts</h2>
            <div id='contactsList'>
                <table class='contactsEditor'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                        <th>Phone numbers</th>
                    </tr>                   

                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
                                <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: 
$root.removeContact'>Delete</a></div>
                            </td>

                            <td><input data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>                            

                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                                            <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                                            <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addPhone'>Add number</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <p>
                <button data-bind='click: addContact'>Add a contact</button>             
                <button data-bind='click: save, enable: contacts().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
            </p>

            <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
        </div>    
    </body>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="viewmodel.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here's the viewmodel.js:

```
var initialData = [
    { firstName: "Danny", lastName: "LaRusso", phones: [
        { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 121-2121" },
        { type: "Home", number: "(555) 123-4567"}]
    },
    { firstName: "Sensei", lastName: "Miyagi", phones: [
        { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 444-2222" },
        { type: "Home", number: "(555) 999-1212"}]
    }
];

var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
    var self = this;

    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, 
function(contact) {
        return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, 
phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones) };
    }));

    self.addContact = function() {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phones: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function(contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function(contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            type: "",
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function(phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

Comment: why you uppercase the tags in your css like `TR` or `TABLE` ??

Comment: That is how the Knockout examples does it. I seen that and changed them to lowercase...but it did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the selector to select the `th` elements as well:

```
.liveExample table.contactsEditor>tbody>TR > th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```js
var initialData = [{
    firstName: "Danny",
    lastName: "LaRusso",
    phones: [{
        type: "Mobile",
        number: "(555) 121-2121"
      },
      {
        type: "Home",
        number: "(555) 123-4567"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sensei",
    lastName: "Miyagi",
    phones: [{
        type: "Mobile",
        number: "(555) 444-2222"
      },
      {
        type: "Home",
        number: "(555) 999-1212"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
  var self = this;

  self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts,
    function(contact) {
      return {
        firstName: contact.firstName,
        lastName: contact.lastName,
        phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones)
      };
    }));

  self.addContact = function() {
    self.contacts.push({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      phones: ko.observableArray()
    });
  };

  self.removeContact = function(contact) {
    self.contacts.remove(contact);
  };

  self.addPhone = function(contact) {
    contact.phones.push({
      type: "",
      number: ""
    });
  };

  self.removePhone = function(phone) {
    $.each(self.contacts(), function() {
      this.phones.remove(phone)
    })
  };

  self.save = function() {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
  };

  self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.liveExample {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #EEEEDD;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  max-width: 655px;
}

.liveExample input {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.liveExample b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.liveExample p {
  margin-top: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}

.liveExample select[multiple] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8em;
}

.liveExample h2 {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.liveExample TR {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.liveExample TABLE,
.liveExample TD,
.liveExample TH {
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.liveExample TD A {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.liveExample table.contactsEditor>tbody>TR > th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.liveExample td input {
  width: 8em;
}

li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Contacts Editor</title>

  <link href="C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Web Dev\Javascript and 
jQuery\Knockout.js\Examples\Contacts editor\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='liveExample'>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <div id='contactsList'>
      <table class='contactsEditor'>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Phone numbers</th>
        </tr>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
              <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: 
$root.removeContact'>Delete</a></div>
            </td>

            <td><input data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>

            <td>
              <table>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                  <tr>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addPhone'>Add number</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <p>
      <button data-bind='click: addContact'>Add a contact</button>
      <button data-bind='click: save, enable: contacts().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
    </p>

    <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="viewmodel.js"></script>

</html>
```

### Update

You could use `border-collapse: collapse` to apply the border to all `tr` elements in the table:

```
.liveExample table.contactsEditor > tbody >tr  {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.liveExample table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```js
var initialData = [{
    firstName: "Danny",
    lastName: "LaRusso",
    phones: [{
        type: "Mobile",
        number: "(555) 121-2121"
      },
      {
        type: "Home",
        number: "(555) 123-4567"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sensei",
    lastName: "Miyagi",
    phones: [{
        type: "Mobile",
        number: "(555) 444-2222"
      },
      {
        type: "Home",
        number: "(555) 999-1212"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
  var self = this;

  self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts,
    function(contact) {
      return {
        firstName: contact.firstName,
        lastName: contact.lastName,
        phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones)
      };
    }));

  self.addContact = function() {
    self.contacts.push({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      phones: ko.observableArray()
    });
  };

  self.removeContact = function(contact) {
    self.contacts.remove(contact);
  };

  self.addPhone = function(contact) {
    contact.phones.push({
      type: "",
      number: ""
    });
  };

  self.removePhone = function(phone) {
    $.each(self.contacts(), function() {
      this.phones.remove(phone)
    })
  };

  self.save = function() {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
  };

  self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.liveExample {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #EEEEDD;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  max-width: 655px;
}

.liveExample input {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.liveExample b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.liveExample p {
  margin-top: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}

.liveExample select[multiple] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8em;
}

.liveExample h2 {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.liveExample TR {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.liveExample TABLE,
.liveExample TD,
.liveExample TH {
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.liveExample TD A {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.liveExample table.contactsEditor > tbody >tr  {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.liveExample table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.liveExample td input {
  width: 8em;
}

li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Contacts Editor</title>

  <link href="C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Web Dev\Javascript and 
jQuery\Knockout.js\Examples\Contacts editor\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='liveExample'>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <div id='contactsList'>
      <table class='contactsEditor'>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Phone numbers</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
              <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: 
$root.removeContact'>Delete</a></div>
            </td>

            <td><input data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>

            <td>
              <table>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                  <tr>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addPhone'>Add number</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <p>
      <button data-bind='click: addContact'>Add a contact</button>
      <button data-bind='click: save, enable: contacts().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
    </p>

    <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="viewmodel.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: That won't work as the intent here is to surround each contact with that silver border. Sorry if I was not clearer on that. I added a picture above to clarify.

Comment: @user3020047 I thought you meant just the header elements. I just updated the second snippet in my answer. Do you want the look like that?

Comment: That is how it should look. I see that all you added is just that collapse rule. However, why does it work for Knockout's example WITHOUT your additional rule? I added the link above to their example and they do not have your new rule in there.

Comment: They actually do have the `border-collapse` set on `.content table` selector. Try inspecting the table element in Dev tools.

Comment: I just looked further at Knockout's run and they have a normalize.css file they are also using (which they did not indicate that in their example) and in that file, their is your  border-collapse: collapse; CSS rule. So your solution IS correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed the same thing.